# Adding two character arrays and storing the result as characters in another char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, ascii, modulo

I want to add two character arrays and store the result as characters in another character array. 
The addition involves addition of two english letters from the two arrays as operands.
The addition will wrap around z back to a .

eg.
Input:Array1 and Array 2 and output is Array 3

Array 1 :abcdeyz

Array 2 :aaaaaaa

Array 3 :bcdefza

Below is a part of my code which is not working.
Kindly suggest any changes

```
    int c = 0;

    char array3[] = new char[count] ;    

for(int a=0;a<array1.length;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<array2.length;b++)
        {
            int temp = (array1[a] + array2[b]) % 26 ;
            array3[c] = (char) temp ; 
            c++ ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so add up the ascii values?

Comment: @jgr208 No, its more like the [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), but with variable ranges.

Comment: That will not add the two arrays together

Comment: @Tom Yes but every character gets replaced with a different character depending on the input from the 2 arrays

Comment: Why do you use 2 nested loops? You only need one `for` loop and if the "key" isn't long enough, then it should copied, until it is long enough.

Comment: @Tom what i tried is : I took the key as an input and then copied it into and array(array2) which is of the size of array 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fixed and working example on how to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] array1 = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'y', 'z'};
    char[] array2 = new char[] {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'};
    char[] array3 = new char[array1.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      array3[i] = toChar((toInt(array1[i]) + toInt(array2[i]) + 1) % 26);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array3));
}

private static int toInt(char chr) {
    return chr - 'a';
}

private static char toChar(int value) {
    return (char)(value + 'a');
}
```

There are some thinks to notice here (except the `- 'a'` part, the other answers mentioned that already):

- you only need one loop for this task. If you use 2 nested loops, then you'll add each letter of `array1` with every letter of `array2`. And you'll a larger `array3`. And since the result doesn't match the desired result ... :)
- the `+ 1` in `toInt(array2[i]) + 1` is necessary, because `char - 'a'` is "zero-based". Therefore `'a' + 'b'` would result in `'b'` and not `'c'`, because you'll calculate `0 + 1` (which will be `'b'` if you "convert" it back to char by adding `'a'`) (I hope this is understandable expressed :D)
- it is necessary that `array2` has at least the same length as 'array1'. It is almost like [padding in cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29). (I've omitted the padding part to keep this code short)

Comment: could you kindly expand on your first point : if I use 2 loops i would need a larger array 3

Comment: Let assume you have these to arrays: `{'a', 'b'}` and `{'c', 'd'}`. The length for `array3` should be 2 as well. But `array3` will be `{'a+c', 'a+d', 'b+c', 'b+d'}`, because you add each entry of `array1` with *every* entry of `array2` and not only the corresponding entry (i.e. on the same index).

Comment: :So if I have 2 large arrays using two loops may be an incorrect approach, because the size of my third array will be very big

Comment: And the result will be wrong. Like in the exaple above: expected: `{'d', 'f'}`, actual: `{'d', 'e', 'e', 'f'}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate @tom : your code worked finally getting the cipher text correctly

Answer (score 2):

Hint - value of 'a' is not 0

The issue is in the line -

```
int temp = (array1[a] + array2[b]) % 26 ;
```

Here is the modified code (assuming all characters are lower case)-

```
    int c = 0;

    char array3[] = new char[count] ;    

for(int a=0;a<array1.length;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<array2.length;b++)
        {
            int temp = ( (array1[a]-'a') + (array2[b]-'a')) % 26 ;
            array3[c] = (char) (temp+'a') ; 
            c++ ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if array1[a]='x' and array2[b]='z'? We need the %26 to keep in the range [0,26) as per OP's statement "The addition will wrap around z back to a"

Comment: Can you do me a favor? Try this code and see if you get the desired output of array3. I assume, the first thing, you'll get is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Depends on the count. As per OP, it will be array1.length*array2.length. You can check here - http://ideone.com/r20S1F

Comment: But this is not what OP wanted as output.

Comment: @Tom  yes it is giving a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Increased the size of the array 3 but all i see printed on my console is "?" :question marks

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulo of 26 is a good way of handling a-z to 1-26 conversion.  This way your program can be agnostic about the actual ASCII character numbers.

Some other concerns:

1. **Case Insensitivity**.  I would recommend converting your letters to lowercase before processing them.
2. **Handling of exceptional cases**.  What if your arrays are different lengths?  Or what if they have a character that isn't a
   letter?

The below code is one way to handle these things.

```
public static int letterToInt(char letter) {
    char letterToConvert = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
    int codeForA = (int)'a';
    int numberOfLetter = ((int)letterToConvert) - codeForA + 1;
    if(numberOfLetter < 1 || numberOfLetter > 26) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The character argument can only be a-z or A-Z, but was '" + letter + "'");
    }
    return numberOfLetter;
}

public static char intToLetter(int number) {
    if(number < 1 || number > 26) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The number can only be 1-26, but was " + number);
    }
    int codeForA = (int)'a';
    return (char)(codeForA + number - 1);
}

public static char addLetters(char letter1, char letter2) {
    int numberFromAddedLetters =
            letterToInt(letter1) + letterToInt(letter2);
    int modulo = numberFromAddedLetters % 26;
    return intToLetter(modulo == 0 ? 26 : modulo);
}

public static char[] addLetterArrays(char[] array1, char[] array2) {
    char[] longerArray;
    char[] shorterArray;
    if(array1.length >= array2.length) {
        longerArray = array1;
        shorterArray = array2;
    } else {
        longerArray = array2;
        shorterArray = array1;
    }

    char[] addedLetters = new char[longerArray.length];
    for(int index = 0; index < longerArray.length; index++) {
        if(index < shorterArray.length) {
            addedLetters[index] = addLetters(longerArray[index], shorterArray[index]);
        } else {
            addedLetters[index] = longerArray[index];
        }
    }
    return addedLetters;
}

// Test it out
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] letters1 = "abcdeyz".toCharArray();
    char[] letters2 = "aaaaaaa".toCharArray();
    // Prints [b, c, d, e, f, z, a]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(addLetterArrays(letters1, letters2)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
int temp = (((array1[a] - 'a') + (array2[b] - 'a')) % 26) + 'a';
```

what this does is convert both characters into their respective place in the alphabet, perform addition modulo the number of characters in the alphabet for the wraparound effect, and convert back to the correct ascii value.

Note that your code was having trouble because you were acting as though the alphabet's ascii values were their respective places in the alphabet itself, which is incorrect.